# Make Smarty field required

Tags: php, html, smarty

i have a piece of code ( part of a smarrty html page ) that it creates a dropdown list of locations and once one is selected, a second one appears having the sublocations.

The problem is that the second field is not required and i would like to make it required as it is crutial for the website to function well enough.

```
                                <div class="control-group" style="margin-top:50px">
                                    <label class="control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <h5 style="font-weight:700">Enter Your Property City or Municipality</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {if $field_enable_listing_location == "yes"}
                                <div class="control-group {$warning_listing_location_1}">
                                    <label class="control-label">{$field_name_listing_location} <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="controls">

                                        <div id="listing_location_1" style="current:block; padding-top:0px">
                                            <select name="listing_location_1" id="box_listing_location_1" class="span6 m-wrap" onchange="find_child_location(this.value, {$setup_import_loc_level}, 'system_setup_location_ajax_sum.php?parent='+this.value, 'system_setup_location_ajax_list.php?box_level=2&box_width=400&box_class=span6 m-wrap&box_name=listing_location&parent='+this.value, 1, 'listing_location_2', 'listing_location_notification'); change_color('box_listing_location_1', '#FFFFFF', 'black', 'lbl_listing_location_1', 'black')">
                                            <option value="">Choose your property region</option>
                                            {section name=var loop=$location_lv1_id}
                                            <option value="{$location_lv1_id[var]}" {if $location_lv1_id[var] == $clisting_location_1} selected {/if} >{$location_lv1_name[var]}</option>
                                            {/section}
                                            </select>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="required_listing_location_1" value="text" />
                                        </div>

                                        {section name=var loop=$location_current}

                                            <div id="listing_location_{$location_current[var]}" style="current:none; padding-top:{$location_padding[var]}">
                                            {if $location_show[var] == "yes"}
                                                <select name="listing_location_{$location_current[var]}" class="span6 m-wrap" onchange="find_child_location(this.value, {$setup_import_loc_level}, 'system_setup_location_ajax_sum.php?parent='+this.value, 'system_setup_location_ajax_list.php?box_level={$location_next[var]}&box_width=400&box_class=span6 m-wrap&box_name=listing_location&parent='+this.value, {$location_current[var]}, 'listing_location_{$location_next[var]}', 'listing_location_notification');">
                                                {section name=sub loop=$location_list_id[var]}
                                                <option value="{$location_list_id[var][sub]}" {if $location_list_id[var][sub] == $location_value[var]} selected {/if}>{$location_list_name[var][sub]}</option>
                                                {/section}
                                                </select>
                                            {/if}
                                            </div>

                                        {/section}
```

somewhere after that there is :

```
                        listing_location_1:                         {ldelim} required: true {rdelim},
```

and somewhere else :

```
                        listing_location_1:                         {ldelim} required: "Please fill this field." {rdelim},
```

Is there a way i could make the second field mandatory ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're editing your HTML, have you added REQUIRED to the end of the tag?

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="bar" REQUIRED />
```

While this works in Modern Browsers (chrome +20, Firefox 18+ and Safari) It isn't guaranteed to work in older browsers (guess... yep IE). So my next question to you would be how are you doing your validation? JS or PHP?

Comment: I've just added this :
   listing_location_2:                         {ldelim} required: true {rdelim},
and it worked for a reason.
I added the piece of code you suggested but didn't worked on smarty.

Comment: Hmm I would think that html is html but maybe it's filtering it out when it renders out in the browser. Glad you figured it out though